# Can you wrap a Func<EFContext, TResult> inside an Entities Context for reuse?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, func

I was curious on a reuse pattern that may be possible and wanted to see if others have tried it.  Essentially I have these for example of standard EF 6.1.3 returns:

```
private IEnumerable<TypeTran> GetTypes()
{
  using (var context = new ExpensesEntities())
  {
    return context.tdType.Select(x => new TypeTran(x.TypeID, x.Description)).Where(x => x.TypeId != 3);
  }
}

private List<Category> GetCurrentCategories()
{
  using (var context = new ExpensesEntities())
  {
    return context.tdCategory.Select(x => new Category(x.CategoryID, x.Description)).ToList();
  }
}
```

Don't really worry about TypeTran or Category.  Suffice to say they are just POCOs and could be anything.  They are just abstracting a layer removal of EF so I can have more after market effects on a Model object without effecting the T4 generated objects from the database.  This model works fine but there is a lot more retrieval patterns so I was curious if I could do something like:

```
private TReturn RunContextWithOption<TReturn>(Func<ExpensesEntities, TReturn> func)
{
  using (var context = new ExpensesEntities())
  {
    return func.Invoke(context);
  }
}
```

But when I attempt to run it I am doing the syntax wrong and I also am not seeing a way to use the context without pre defining it.

```
//Wrong won't run
private List<TypeTran> GetTypes()
{
  var cont = new ExpensesEntities();
  return RunContextWithOption<List<TypeTran>>((cont) => cont.tdType.Select(x => new TypeTran(x.TypeID, x.Description)).Where(x => x.TypeId != 3));

}
```

So it becomes the chicken or the egg, I want the context to be auto invoked with a helper, yet I cannot as I need that in an arg it appears.   Has anyone else tried something similar to make their repo pattern merely less lines of code?  This may be bad practice but I am generally for less lines of code and using private helpers whenever possible rather than repeating using(var context...) ad infinitum.

Comment: So you want a generic method to return a list of entities of unknown type by passing in a filter/where clause?

Comment: Sort of.  In my hope, I could have the func say the context object like tdType, teCategory, etc...  The keeps becoming the function is accepted but my use is always thwarted by things like: "You cannot convert this to this".  Essentially this is for a bunch of 'GetAll' returns where the only variable is the type in and the type out.  Sometimes they may have a Where clause, but not always.

Comment: What do you mean by "entity generated object"? It's not clear.

Comment: In the T4 template of Entity Framework it auto generates POCO objects that relate to database tables.  When you call them in a context it is like 'context.(generated object)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is what you need. I've included an optional `Where` clause and it would be pretty trivial to include, say, an `OrderBy` too:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntities<TEntity>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null)
    where TEntity : class
{
    using (var context = new ExpensesEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> data = context.Set<TEntity>();
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(predicate);
        }

        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var diedOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
var zombiesOlderThan30Days = GetEntities<Zombie>(z => 
    z.Name == "Bob" && z.DiedOn > diedOn);

var allZombies = GetnEntities<Zombie>();
```

Comment: Thanks that looks almost exactly what I wanted but I am getting an error on the line of 'context.Set<TEntity>'.  It states: 'Error CS0452 The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()''.  Not sure if you are using your EF context in a different way.  I know I upgraded from EF 4 originally on this and the context is set like 'ExpensesEntities : DbContext' and has members like 'public virtual DbSet<tdCategory> tdCategory { get; set;} ...

Comment: Oops, typed it out without confirming it compiles, try again!

Comment: Same error, I need to go away for most of the day but will come back over the weekend and check on this and see where it is at.  Thanks for the help thus far.  Sorry if it seemed a little vague what I was trying to do.  You look like you got the jist of it now.

Comment: Make sure you add in the `where` constraint at the top. Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: Works great.  Like you said I just needed to ensure there was a where clause after the method signature.  Thanks.